# Open file takes more than 2 seconds

Tags: python

I am trying to read the first line (only 1 line) from the file. I added a timer and this command takes more than 2 seconds. Why is that? (This is a real time application)

How do I reduce the time to less than 1 second?

Python 2.7

```py
def Get_CPU_Usage():
        print "Checking CPU usage"
        start_time = time.time()
        try:
                with open("/tmp/Automation/cpu.log", 'r') as control_fd:
                        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
                        return str(control_fd.readline())
        except:
                return "0;0;0;0"
```

Comment: What kind of file are you trying to read? Text file? and how large is it? Where is it stored? Is this a problem with one particular file or all files in general?

Comment: text file, 1 line, output is such as: 0;0;0;0 (up to 100;100;100;100) - so maximum 15 chars

Comment: I think that the other questions were important also -- is the file local? It seems to be, given that it is apparently on /tmp. Is it a small or very large file? And what happens when you attempt to open a different file? Does it also take a long time? When I run this code on my computer it takes far less than a second to run.

Comment: real file, or a named pipe (FIFO)? named pipes block open until "both ends" are open. You can open with `O_NONBLOCK` to avoid this.

Comment: local file, 15 chars - so very small file. all file system commands takes long time (even "ls"), but regular commands are running fast

Comment: Which system are you using? Based on `ls` I am assuming you are using linux? Does using `ls` in terminal take long time or is it a python specific issue? I am sorry but there are so like a gazillion factors to consider.